# why diode electrons go p-n junction

Tags: transistors, diodes, pn-junction

The n electrons go in the p side and there are holes in n side but why it happens. they are pulled towards p side but isn't it ok that they are in their own atom ,or is it to do with atom want to give electrons

Are the electrons pulled more towards the p side than their nuclei;if so then why

Comment: There's a misconception in your question. N electrons are in the conduction band, and hence aren't bound to a particular atom.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but I'm going to interpret it as "Why do electrons from the N-doped side fill holes in the P-doped side near the junction without an electric field applied?"

There are two influences on the conduction-band electrons.  One is obvious--the ionic attraction to the charged nuclei.  (As nanofarad points out, they are not strongly associated with individual atoms, but atoms which would be positively charged in their absence continue to attract them en masse.)

The second is the tendency of the electrons to seek a lower energy level.  Those levels are already filled on the N side, but available in the P material.  As such, some electrons give up energy to associate with P nuclei on a lower valence level, resulting in a standing electric charge across the junction.  This doesn't result in a voltage at the terminals, as the standing voltage across the junction is still balanced on the scale of the substrate.

Hope I answered the right question.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is "how do you get free electrons", at room temperature, there is enough thermal energy in the crystal structure of the device to "dislodge" some of the electrons from the silicon (or germanium, or whatever) and nearly all of the charge carriers from the dopant materials.